# How do you query multiple asset types using Version One rest API?

Tags: api, rest, versionone

I would like to get the story name and number from querying tasks by owner. I am wondering if this is possible in a single query or if I will have to first query for the specific task and then look up the story using the task identifier in two separate queries.

**Input**: Task.Owners.Name

**Output**: Story.Name,Story.Number

**Task Attributes**

```
*Owners.Name

*TaskID
```

**Story Attributes**

```
*TaskID

*Name

*Number
```

I am able to call the REST api like below:

rest-1.v1/Data/Task?where=Task.Owners.Name='{{ownerName}}'&sel=Task.Owners.Name,Task.Number,Parent

Is there a way to query the Story endpoint with only task attributes specified in the where condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to query the Story endpoint with only task attributes
>   specified in the where condition?

I am starting from the Story endpoint, iterating through all Stories filtering by the Tasks that belong to the current Story, and filtering by the Task's Owners attribute.

```
 /rest-1.v1/Data/Story?sel=Number,Children:Task[Owners.Name='pinky']&where=Children:Task[Owners.Name='pinky']
```

(1) sel=Children:Task[Owners.Name='pinky']- The Children multi-relation returns all children of a Story which are Tests and Tasks.  I used downcasting to filter down to only Tasks.

(2) Inside of the [ ], is where you can add a specific filter to the data return from Children:Task.

(3) @where=Children:Task[Owners.Name='pinky'] is a way to filter out items that have empty elements.  Experiment with it by removing it and see the difference in output.